# Generic cell renderer for JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I want to make a JTable cell renderer which will be able to recognize a type of data and use a appropriate representation.

More specific, i want my table to be able to recognize if type of data is Collection and in that case to use JComboBox for representation (in other cases a standard representation: JCheckBox for boolean type and JLabel for other types and for that I'm using custom model's method `getColumnClass()`)

I don't know the type of data in advance, in which column will be Collection or even is there will be Collection at all so I can't use a standard way of

`JComboBox cell renderer TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);`

or similar which I'm familiar with.

Please help :)

Comment: *"More specific, i want my table to be able to recognize if type of data is Collection and in that case to use JComboBox for representation (in other cases a standard representation: JCheckBox for boolean type and JLabel for other types and for that I'm using custom model's method `getColumnClass()`)*" - that sounds more like the functionality of a TableCellEditor. The purpose of the getColumnClass method of the TableModel is to allow it to look up renderers/editors from the JTable's available registry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DefaultRendering mechanism inside JTable, reusing this mechanism to apply for each cell:

```
tableView.setDefaultRenderer(TitleViewCell.class, new TitleTableCellRenderer.class());
tableView.setDefaultRenderer(DataViewCell.class, new DataTableCellRenderer.class());
```

Here you can subclass a JTable into a JTableView for example:

```
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class JTableView extends JTable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1350656893711208356L;

    public JTableView(TableModel tableModel)
    {
        super(tableModel);
    }

    public TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer(int row, int column)
    {
        Object value = getValueAt(row, column);
        if (value != null)
        {
            return getDefaultRenderer(value.getClass());
        }
        return super.getCellRenderer(row, column);
    }
};
```